# How to implement lazy loading for a multi-tier application

Tags: angular

I have a 3-tier application and I'm having problems with the architecture. Here are the example urls:

```
/ (base url)
dummy-configuration/
dummy-configuration/dummyModel   
dummy-configuration/dummyModel/dummyData
```

So I've got a *dummy config* module, an *dummyModel* module and a *dummyData* component. However, I only put router outlet directives in the *app component html* and the *dummy config* html. This is where I first went wrong, I believe. Don't I need a router outlet at each level?

My *app-routing.module* file lazy loads my *dummy configuration module*:

```
 {
    path: 'dummy-configuration',
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('./dummy-configuration/dummy-configuration.module').then(
        (p) => p.DummyConfigurationModule
      ),
  }
```

The *dummy configuration routing module* then lazy loads its children:

```
children: [
  {
    path: {PATH},
    loadChildren: () =>
      import('../dummyModel/dummy-model.module').then((m) => m.DummyModule),
  }
]
```

And the *Dummy module* will load its children:

```
children: [
  {
    path: 'childOne',
    component: childOneComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'childTwo',
    component: childTwoComponent,
  }
]
```

What I've achieved is lazy loading of the *dummy config* and "dummy model" modules. But what I want is also to lazy load the component routes for the *dummy model* and I don't know how to do it. How can I re-architect this correctly? Honestly, I'm a little lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `children` attribute you do need a router-outlet in which the children can be rendered. In your case though, you can just add the first module just like you showed by loading it at the `plan-configuration` path.

The second module you can just load at the `plan-configuration/fsa` path, wit will then correctly handle the `profile` and `dependents` routes without needing another router-outlet but instead being rendered in the main one.

In short, just import the `ra-fsa` module in `app-routing` with `plan-configuration/fsa` as your path.

Comment: You want me to move the "fsa" module from being imported in "plan config" to being imported in "app-routing"? I don't understand that. I do, however, get your point that I don't need a router outlet at every level. I have a nested router on the "plan config" level and can render the "profile" and "dependents" components there.

Comment: That's exactly what I am suggesting since you don't want to render the components of the `fsa` module inside one of you `plan config`  components, the solution is to move the module up to where you actually want to render the components. Id you want your URL to still include the `plan-configuration` bit, you can just add that to the path.

Comment: Ok, I see your point - thank you. However, I do want the "fsa" module and all its components to render in "plan config"; that's where they belong, where it makes sense. When a user enters the site they click a button to load the "plan config" and they click another button to load "fsa". How about the last part of my question? I was asked by a developer to do lazy routing of the component routes. Is that even a thing? I thought all I needed to do was lazy load the modules.

Comment: I might have misread your question a little there. You can only load modules in a lazy way. If you wanted to load both those routes in a lazy way, you could but those components into separate modules and load them at the `''` path, meaning an empty path.
So the `fsa` module had `loadChildren` routes and both the `profile` and `dependents` path then.

Comment: I think I get it. In order to do a lazy routing of those component routes then I need to put "profile" and "dependents" in separate modules and have them defined on the "" path, right?

Comment: Inside their respective modules the components would be at the `''` path, correct. Since that's the only route that module serves and the rest of the path is already defined by various routes that use the `loadChildren` attributes.

It's not necessarily a good idea to do this though. I'm just pointing out how it could be done.

Comment: Thank you, I'll mark your answer as the accepted answer. Personally, I will follow your advice and not split the components into separate modules just to achieve a lazy routing. I'll just tell the developer that the modules are loaded lazily and there's really no such thing as lazy routing.